# Ionic 4 iOS app using APNS Push Notifications without a third party service

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I would like to build an Ionic 4 app for iOS platform only (no android/windows/web version required) that supports APNS based Push Notifications. My backend is going to be NodeJS/ExpressJS based. After so many days of searching I wasn't able to find one solid example/solution that does not use a third party service such as OneSignal or Firebase. This is an enterprise app and we cannot use a thirdparty service other than Apple's APNS. We'd like to send the notification from our NodeJS backend to APNS (which I am well aware of how to implement). What've I've been suffering with is to find a good Ionic 4 library that allows me to interact with the OS's Push Notification capabilities such as capturing device token, listening for notifications when app is in foreground etc. Could someone please direct me to a good resource that shows how to accomplish this straightforward requirement of using Ionic 4 to work with ios push notifications sent via APNS?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for you is to implement this functionality in swift and create a plugin which will call your javascript code.

I think [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) is a simple example of how to implement push notifications with swift.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin, which is popular and well mantained. It supports both **APNS** and Firebase, and it is remarkably well documented. Not sure about Ionic 4 support, but that's a solid starting point anyway.